# How to move SQL records from one table to another inside a trigger

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-trigger

I have a sql table (table A) with a column called 'Number'.  Inside a trigger (I have an AFTER INSERT,UPDATE trigger) I want to move all records that have the same Number to a different table (say table B)

So if its an insert I want to move all records that have that Number to table B so only the new record exists in the original table (table A).

If its an update I want to make a copy of the record being updated to table B (with old values).

so table B is a history table that holds all previous records and table A should only have one entry per Number.

would be nice to put in the existing AFTER INSERT/UPDATE but if I need another trigger that's fine.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What about Deleted?

Comment: Does it have to be a trigger? Alternatively, you could do that work in the proc that you are using for your table updates. You will have your key column available in the proc and then you could move all the affected records from Table A to Table B prior to the changes in Table A. Just a thought.

Comment: records are never deleted...only updated or inserted

Answer (score 0):

This turned out not as complicated as I thought...

```
(@itemId set from cursor)

SELECT @tempNumber = [Number] FROM tableA WHERE Id = @itemId;

if (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM deleted)) --is insert
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO tableB SELECT *, GETDATE() AS CreatedDate FROM tableA WHERE Number=@tempNumber AND Id != @itemId
  DELETE FROM tableA WHERE Number=@tempNumber AND Id != @itemId
END
```

i decided not to create an entry on update but if needed you I believe you would just do an ELSE and SELECT from deleted and then INSERT.

Hope this helps someone!